# не запускается команда в cron

Tags: java, ubuntu, cron

пытаюсь запустить такую команду в cron

```
25 12 * * * java -jar /var/www/fileName.jar 4 >> /var/www/ekey.log
```

В логах крона пишет

```
Aug 19 12:25:01 instance-1 CRON[32089]: (login) CMD (java -jar /var/www/fileName.jar 4 >> /var/www/mylog.log)
```

дальше ничего, в top задача не появляется , файл лога пустой. Подскажите

Comment: а если полный путь до java указать?

Comment: замените `>>` на `&>>` — вы забыли *stderr* перенаправить в тот же файл. p.s. как обычно для вопросов, у которых автор поставил метку `cron`, к программе *cron* вопрос не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения.

Comment: обычно в вопросах с кроном не знаю, о том, что крон запускается немного в другом окружении и там немного другие дефолтные пути. Я бы для начала их и проверил бы, указав полный путь к java.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала просто посмотрите, какое окружение у cron:

```
15 * * * * env > /var/www/cronenv.out
```

Проверьте пути. Т.к. стандартный вывод ошибок не перенаправлен, то скорее всего cron не находит java, в этом случае файл с логом будет пустой.