# Не запускается php скрипт через crontab

Tags: php, cron, crontab

Есть cron файл cron.txt который присвоен пользователю www-data:

```
#cron.txt file
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /projects/cron.php >> /projects/cron.logs
```

если в ручную выполнить команду:

> /usr/bin/php /projects/cron.php
>   то все сработает. Но crontab не хочет самостоятельно запускать скрипт и отправляет на почту ошибку:
>
> Could not open input file: /projects/cron.php

В чем может быть проблема?

P.S.:
Права на все файлы 0777

Файл указывался через команду: crontab -u www-data /projects/cron.txt

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707980/#comment1055862_707980

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вызов php скрипта через crontab](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709079/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-php-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-crontab)